# MsalRedirectComponent calls store after login

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, ngrx, ngrx-store, msal

`I'm using Msal Login with NGRX
created actions, effects and reducers and in login logout button calling dispatcher

I also want to use MsalRedirectComponent in bootstrap so that it automatically redirect to microsoft login page but we are not calling through dispatcher so token store in local storage .

```
version
 "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.5.8",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.37.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",

App Module
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,  MsalRedirectComponent
  ]

created store and in login button calling dispatcher
 login() {
    this.store.dispatch(login());
  }
actions 
export const login = createAction('[Auth] Login');
export const loginSuccess = createAction('[Auth] Login Success', props<{ token: string }>());
export const loginFailure = createAction('[Auth] Login Failure', props<{ error: any }>());

effetcs
 login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.login),
      exhaustMap(() =>
        this.authService.login().pipe(
          map(token => AuthActions.loginSuccess({ token })),
          catchError(error => of(AuthActions.loginFailure({ error })))
        )
      )
    )
  );

reducer
  initialState,
  on(AuthActions.login, state => ({ ...state, loading: true })),
  on(AuthActions.loginSuccess, (state, { token }) => ({ ...state, token, loading: false })),
  on(AuthActions.loginFailure, (state, { error }) => ({ ...state, error, loading: false })),
```

How can include MsalRedirectComponent

`